# How to implement bi-directional assosiation between Classes?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, object-oriented-analysis

I am trying to design software for video rental. I would like `Movie` class to have list of `Actor *` who acted in the movie. I would also like `Actor` to have list of `Movie *`, in which he has acted.

1. How to ensure that there is no inconsistency between the two lists?
2. How to initialize `Movie` object, whose `Actor` Object is not present[but will have to be created]?

Comment: As for 2, you have to add Actors first, and only then add movies using those actors. Anyway, in a typical database design, you'd have *three* columns: Actors, Movies, and ActorMovieRelation, linking the former two. I guess from [normalization perspective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) this would be a better design than what you're proposing, but I'm not a RDB expert.

Answer (score 1):

You can ensure consistency between the two by taking control of how the user can manage the relationships and protecting invariants. For example, ensure that an `Actor`'s collection of `Movies` and a `Movie`'s collection of `Actors` can only be manipulated via methods you control:

```
class Actor
{
   private readonly IList<Movie> movies = new List<Movies>();

   public IEnumerable Movies
   {
      get
      {
         return this.movies;
         // This could be return this.Movies.AsReadOnly() if
         // you're concerned someone might still try and cast
         // from IEnumerable
      }
   }
}
```

Furthermore, ensure that the owning class maintains the integrity of the relationships when either side changes:

```
class Actor
{
   public void AddMovie(Movie movie)
   {
      this.movies.Add(movie);

      movie.AddActor(this);
   }
}
```

**N.B. This technique must also be replicated on the `Movie` class.**

I don't understand what you're asking in the second part of your question.

Comment: Say a new movie is released. The actors in it are new faces, so the corresponding Actor object are absent. That will require to create new Actor object first. How to handle that case in transparent manner. Thanks.

Comment: In that case, I think my answer still stands. Whether you add an `Actor` to a `Movie` or vice-versa, the model must maintain its integrity. My solution supports that.